# Scan for bluetooth devices on a remote android mobile using InTheHand namespace in C#

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth

In my project I have to scan to bluetooth devices on a Android phone and get connected to the particular device. For this I am using InTheHand namespace and the code is pasted below. Issue is that, the radio is launched on my laptop where I am executing the code instead of the Android mobile where I intend to run it. So I have used the overloaded method of BluetoothClient(endpoint). But this gives and unhadled Exception :

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketsException'

Additional information:

> The requested address is not valid in its context"

But address is what the bluetooth address of my android phone . Please help me find the mistake in my code.My Code

```
 void ScanForBluetoothClients()
        {

            BluetoothDeviceInfo[] dev;
            BluetoothDeviceInfo td = null;
            string Addr = "00:03:AA:F3:FB:E3";
            addr = BluetoothAddress.Parse("0003AAF3FBE3");

            BluetoothEndPoint endPoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(addr, BluetoothService.SerialPort);
            BluetoothClient localClient = new BluetoothClient(endPoint);
          //  localClient.Connect(endPoint);
            //localClient.Connect(endPoint);

            dev = localClient.DiscoverDevices();
            foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in dev)
            {                      
                   if (d.DeviceAddress == addr)//my device name
                   {
                      td = d;
                      break;
                   }
              }

             try
               {
                    addr = td.DeviceAddress;

                    if (!BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(addr, null)) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Request failed");
                    }
                }
              catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + e.Message);
                    Console.Read();
                }
```